# how are the p-values in lmrob() calculated?

Tags: r, p-value, robust

I need to do a robust regression with lmrob(). For that I need to know how the p-value in the summary is calculated. I can not find anything in the documentation. Maybe anybody has an idea.

Thanks

Comment: 1) When a function is not a base function, please post the name of the package where it comes from. In this case is it `robustbase`? 2) R is open source and you can see a function's source code by typing its name `robustbase:::summary.lmrob` or `summary.lmrob` at a R prompt. Or download its source code from CRAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The p value is calculated from a Student's t distribution using the function `stats::pt`. The relevant code can be found in the body of the function `robustbase:::summary.lmrob`, which you can look at [here](https://github.com/cran/robustbase/blob/master/R/lmrob.R#L522)

The line of the function where the coefficient table, including the p values are calculated, is:

```r
ans$coefficients <- if (ans$converged) 
   cbind(est, se, tval, 2 * pt(abs(tval), df, lower.tail = FALSE))
```

Here, `est` is the vector of model estimates, `se` is the standard error (obtained from the square root of the covariance matrix) and `tval` is `est / se`. The variable `df` is the degrees of freedom.

Here's a simple example of replicating the p values using this method:

```r
library(robustbase)

mod <- lmrob(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

calculated_p_values <- 2 * pt(abs(mod$coefficients / sqrt(abs(diag(mod$cov)))), 
                       mod$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE)

model_p_values <- summary(mod)$coefficients[, 4]

calculated_p_values
#>  (Intercept)           wt 
#> 2.588806e-16 1.283359e-08

model_p_values
#>  (Intercept)           wt 
#> 2.588806e-16 1.283359e-08
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank your very! Do you know if there is a book or anything else in which I can find that "test"?

Comment: @WeareR which test? The t-test? I'm sure you'll get excellent results from searching for "Student's t-test" or "t distribution"

Comment: I mean the the test-statistic which is used in R. Because it is not the same as in the t-test.